# How can I move my local Symfony installation to my server?

Tags: git, symfony

I installed Symfony locally on my mac. The project is called "lovely". I made "lovely" also to a git repository.

Now I want to make a copy to my server. is it possible to just take the folder "lovely" and copy it via ftp into my www/ ?

(I just want to add, that I do not have a github account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can upload your code via FTP and install it to your server as described on [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/deployment.html#basic-file-transfer)

But, I recommend you to use a hosting service for version control; for example [Bitbucked](https://bitbucket.org/product) offers a free private repositories that I think fit perfect for small projects.

**Edit: How to update code using GIT**

After push your code to `origin master` branch, you can execute on your server:

```
//go to project root directory
cd /var/www/lovely/

// download code from git
git pull origin master

// clear cache
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug --no-warmup
php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!